# Elasticsearch multimatch filtered with list of Ids

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm rather new to ES, and i'm trying to solve the following issue.

I've created an index in my Elasticsearch with the following config:

```
client.Indices.Create(lineItemIndex,
                c => c
                    .Settings(s => s
                        .Setting("max_ngram_diff", 13)
                        .Analysis(a => a
                            .Tokenizers(tf => tf
                                .NGram("mynGram", td => td
                                    .MaxGram(15).MinGram(2)))
                            .Analyzers(aa => aa
                                .Custom("mynGram_analyzer", ca => ca
                                    .Filters(new List<string> {"lowercase"})
                                    .Tokenizer("mynGram")))))
                    .Map<ElasticSearchLineItem>(m => m
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Text(ss => ss
                                .Name(na => na.LineItemName)
                                .Fields(ff => ff
                                    .Keyword(k => k
                                        .Name("keyword"))
                                    .Text(tx => tx
                                        .Name("fulltext")
                                        .Analyzer("whitespace")
                                        .Boost(10.0))
                                    .Text(tx => tx
                                        .Name("partial")
                                        .Analyzer("mynGram_analyzer")
                                        .Boost(1.0)))))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Keyword(kw => kw
                                .Name(na => na.LineItemId)
                                .Index(false)))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Keyword(kw => kw
                                .Name(na => na.Id)
                                .Index(false)))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Text(ss => ss
                                .Name(na => na.LineItemNumber)
                                .Fields(ff => ff
                                    .Keyword(k => k
                                        .Name("keyword"))
                                    .Text(tx => tx
                                        .Name("fulltext")
                                        .Analyzer("whitespace")
                                        .Boost(10.0))
                                    .Text(tx => tx
                                        .Name("partial")
                                        .Analyzer("mynGram_analyzer")
                                        .Boost(1.0)))))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Keyword(ss => ss
                                .Name(na => na.SupplierName)
                                .Index(false)))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Keyword(ss => ss
                                .Name(na => na.Unit)
                                .Index(false)))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Number(ss => ss
                                .Name(na => na.PriceAmount)
                                .Type(NumberType.ScaledFloat).ScalingFactor(100)
                                .Index(false)))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Keyword(ss => ss
                                .Name(na => na.Currency)
                                .Index(false)))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Keyword(ss => ss
                                .Name(na => na.SupplierId)
                                .Index(false)))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Text(ss => ss
                                .Name(na => na.ImageUrl)
                                .Index(false)))
                        .Properties(ps => ps
                            .Text(ss => ss
                                .Name(na => na.SupplierPriceListId)
                                .Index(false)))));
```

I my solution we have a searchbox, for searching.

However, we are also suppose to be able to filter the search based on `SupplierId`. So someone doing a search could have multiple `SupplierId` they would want to only see results from.

I've tried to create the following query:

```
var esSearch2 = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticSearchLineItem>()
            .From(0)
            .Take(250)
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Must(mu => mu
                        .MultiMatch(m => m
                            .Fields(f => f
                                .Field(ff => ff
                                    .LineItemName.Suffix("fulltext"))
                                .Field(ff => ff
                                    .LineItemName.Suffix("partial"))
                                .Field(ff => ff
                                    .LineItemNumber.Suffix("fulltext"))
                                .Field(ff => ff
                                    .LineItemNumber.Suffix("partial")))
                        .Query(request.SearchWord)
                        .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                        ))                        
                    .Filter(f => f
                        .Terms(t => t
                            .Verbatim()
                            .Field(p => p
                                .SupplierId.Suffix("keyword"))
                            .Terms(request.ListOfFavorites.ToArray())))));
```

This returns nothing regardless if `request.ListOfFavorites` is empty or not. But if i remove my filter, it will correctly return results.

I guess i'm missing something, or my ordering is messed up. Can anyone help mere here?

Note: i'm using ES 7.5.1 and NEST 7.5.1

EDIT:

I made a change to my index, and removed `Index(false)` from my supplierId field.

Here is the mapping as shown in kibana after the update

```
{
"mapping": {
"properties": {
  "currency": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "index": false
  },
  "id": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "index": false
  },
  "imageUrl": {
    "type": "text",
    "index": false
  },
  "lineItemId": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "index": false
  },
  "lineItemName": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "fulltext": {
        "type": "text",
        "boost": 10,
        "analyzer": "whitespace"
      },
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "partial": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "mynGram_analyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "lineItemNumber": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "fulltext": {
        "type": "text",
        "boost": 10,
        "analyzer": "whitespace"
      },
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "partial": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "mynGram_analyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "priceAmount": {
    "type": "scaled_float",
    "index": false,
    "scaling_factor": 100
  },
  "supplierId": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "supplierName": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "index": false
  },
  "supplierPriceListId": {
    "type": "text",
    "index": false
  },
  "unit": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "index": false
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you mapping you specified `SupplierId` to be [excluded from the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html), so you won't be able to search on it.

```
.Properties(ps => ps
    .Keyword(ss => ss
        .Name(na => na.SupplierId)
        .Index(false)))
```

also, you don't need to specify suffix for your field as it's not defined as multifield, so simply

```
.Filter(f => f
    .Terms(t => t
        .Verbatim()
        .Field(p => p.SupplierId)
        .Terms(request.ListOfFavorites.ToArray())))));
```

is enough.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't help to remove "Index(false)"

Comment: Could you share index mapping from elasticsearch after the change?

Comment: I've made an edit showing the mapping, after i removed Index(false)

Comment: That did the trick. Now it appears to return results :) Now I just need to get more SupplierIds in my ES to see if the filtering works.

Comment: There is one little issue though. If the array of Ids is empty it returns nothing. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should take away `Verbatim` part of the query, so empty array won't be sent to elasticsearch. [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/verbatim-and-strict-query-usage.html).

Comment: That worked. I must have misunderstood what verbatim actually does. But thank you.